# Find the support of the density function of the random variable X + Y .

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The support of a function $f(x)$ is defined to be the set
$\{x : f(x) > 0\}$ .

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two continuous random variables with density
functions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y (y)$, respectively, and suppose that the supports of
these density functions are the intervals $[a, b]$ and $[c, d]$, respectively.

Find the
support of the density function of the random variable $X + Y$ .

Attempt: I tried to set up and take the integral $$\int_{0}^{z} (z-x)(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ and eventually ended getting $\frac{z^3}6$, however this doesnt seem to be right. How would u solve this?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: The intuitive response would be that the support of the sum would be $[a+c,b+d]$ or possibly a subset of that if something peculiar was going on

Comment: How did you get the sum of a+c and b+d? Could u show the steps henry?